# Как изучить фреймворк изнутри?

Tags: java, проектирование, документация

Товарищи! Как изучить библиотеку или фреймворк, или любой другой законченный проект по исходникам, дабы внедриться в процесс разработки и поддержки? Какие есть способы и методы для быстрого погружения в суть кода? Взять любую библиотеку, так там очень много композиций, агрегаций, зависимостей, слушателей, подписчиков и т.п.. Как не запутаться и научиться плавать в чужом коде , как рыба в воде?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно это происходит естественным образом: Сначала осваиваешь фреймворк **полностью** в процессе эксплуатации, пишешь всё более и более сложные проекты с его использованием, начинаешь натыкаться на недокументированные моменты и *тёмные уголки*, чтобы разобраться с ними лазишь в код всё глубже и глубже, потом начинаешь замечать некоторые неудобства, обнаруживаешь, что чего-то не хватает, начинаешь код не только читать, но и исправлять. Однажды понимаешь, что ты давно уже мейнтейнер.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос во многом философский и может содержать множество ответов. От вас также нехватает входящей информации (цели, какие фреймворки и т.д.).

Мое мнение, не обязательно знать как устроено все глубоко из нутри, вам нужно знать базовые моменты к примеру в Laravel (что такое DI, LoC, провайдеры и тд). Все остальное уже прийдет с опытом, по мере необходимости будете разбираться с каждой частью кода.

Тут как с изучением иностранного языка, начинайте с базовых вещей, а потом по мере необходимости будет ясно вам нужен бизнес английский или технический и тд

Успехов